# Delete all values in a dataframe that repeat in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a date column and another column with strings, which are repeated for some dates. I want to drop those strings that repeat in a date from *all* the dataframe.

What I have looks like this:

```
df

date        name
01/01/2020  Lucas
01/01/2020  Marie
01/01/2020  Lucy
01/05/2020  Lucas 
01/05/2020  Marie 
01/05/2020  Lucas 
01/05/2020  Phil
```

In this case,  `df['name']='Lucas'` is repeated in `df['date']='01/05/2020'`. Then, I am trying to remove all rows with `df['name']='Lucas'`, keeping with this dataframe.

```
df2

date        name
01/01/2020  Marie
01/01/2020  Lucy
01/05/2020  Marie 
01/05/2020  Phil
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: what do you need to remove ? remove rows which are same on both columns ? If that's the case df2 should contain row with Lucas

Comment: Just be clear what you want (or just attach output according to your requirements).

Comment: I want to drop those strings that repeat in a date from all the dataframe. In this case, df['name']='Lucas' is repeated in df['date']=01/05/2020. Then, I am trying to remove all rows with df['name']='Lucas'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all of the unique names that are repeated for the same date, and store them in a list. Then subset the dataframe by any rows matching these names. In your case `repeated_names` will only return `['Lucas']`, but this is generalizable.

```
# create a new dataframe where the names 'Lucas' and 'Marie' are repeated for the same date
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01/01/2020']*3 + ['01/05/2020']*4 + ['01/06/2020']*4,'name':['Lucas','Marie','Lucy','Lucas','Marie','Lucas','Phil','Marie','Marie','Lucy','Lucas']})
```

---

Input dataframe:

```
df
          date   name
0   01/01/2020  Lucas
1   01/01/2020  Marie
2   01/01/2020   Lucy
3   01/05/2020  Lucas
4   01/05/2020  Marie
5   01/05/2020  Lucas
6   01/05/2020   Phil
7   01/06/2020  Marie
8   01/06/2020  Marie
9   01/06/2020   Lucy
10  01/06/2020  Lucas
```

---

```
repeated_names = df[df.duplicated()]['name'].values.tolist()
df2 = df[~df['name'].isin(repeated_names)]
```

---

Output dataframe (drops 'Lucas' and 'Marie'):

```
df2
         date  name
2  01/01/2020  Lucy
6  01/05/2020  Phil
9  01/06/2020  Lucy
```

Comment: True, but my dataset is quite big (+2M rows) and I can't check manually those that repeat :/

Comment: So did you want all repeated strings to be removed, not just 'Lucas'?

Comment: Yes, all those that repeat in the same `df['date']`. In this case 'Lucas' repeats in `df['date']=01/05/2020`

Comment: So since 'Lucas' repeats in date, we drop *all* rows containing 'Lucas', including on the date 01/01/01?

Comment: Yes! Exactly,  @Derek

Comment: Will try it now. Thanks!